# org-mode 8 async export process fails

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

The new org-mode exporter has an asynchronous mode which seems pretty cool. However, I can't seem to make it work:

> Initializing asynchronous export process
>
> Process 'org-export-process' exited abnormally

The above errors appear from the export of a LaTeX PDF export that is tested to work with the synchronous process. The same errors appear for an HTML export under the same conditions.

How to fix or debug this?

Answer (score 6):

One possible cause for this issue is the lack of a proper init file for the async process : from what I understand, the async exporter works by starting another emacs session, which needs an init file. This file is specified by the variable `org-export-async-init-file`, which by default points to your init file.

I had the same problem, and based on information from this [thread on the org mailing-list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-09/msg00463.html), I changed this variable so that it points to a file containing the following:

```el
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

(require 'org) 
(require 'ox)
(require 'cl)  
(setq org-export-async-debug nil)
```

That fixed the problem for me.